# Extract Substring with variable start and length

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, text, data-manipulation

I have a field from a *horrible* database in which every value is a string such as

> Field Stage changed from "Kortec Sales Cycle/3 Proposal" to "Kortec Sales Cycle/Postponed"

Or

> Field Stage changed from "Kortec Sales Cycle/5 Evaluate" to "Kortec Sales Cycle/6 Implement"

I need to make 2 calculated columns from this, named 'From' and 'To', with the two values within the quote marks or the number they start with (all 7 stages except 'Postponed' begin with a number).
It's the 'To' field I need the most. I've had a try using `Instr()`, `InStrRev()`, `Left`, and `Mid` functions, but no joy so far. I've also searched online for similar problems but haven't come across any text manipulation requirements like this.
Anyone know how I should go about breaking this down?

Closest I (think I) got was

```
SELECT RIGHT([OppMovs (Base)].[DETAILS], InStrRev([OppMovs (Base)].[DETAILS], 'to')-3) 
FROM [OppMovs (Base)]
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and the results (if you were close or not) and that lets us see what you tried, and gives us a starting point to help you out where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

*Split* can be used to easily extract these:

```vb
s = "Field Stage changed from ""Kortec Sales Cycle/3 Proposal"" to ""Kortec Sales Cycle/Postponed""
? s
Field Stage changed from "Kortec Sales Cycle/3 Proposal" to "Kortec Sales Cycle/Postponed"

? Split(Split(s, "from """)(1), """")(0)
Kortec Sales Cycle/3 Proposal

? Split(Split(s, "to """)(1), """")(0)
Kortec Sales Cycle/Postponed
```

However, for use in a query, you must create small helper functions like:

```vb
Public Function GetFrom(ByVal Value As String) As String

    GetFrom = Split(Split(Value, "from """)(1), """")(0)

End Function


Public Function GetTo(ByVal Value As String) As String

    GetTo = Split(Split(Value, "to """)(1), """")(0)

End Function
```